# How to detect TOR usage with Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, tor, sniffing

I use TOR inside a Virtual Machine. I run Wireshark on my Host. I want to detect TOR usage (for learning/studying) with Wireshark but don't know how. I've tried this:

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/13590/tor-detection

but tshark output doesn't show any cert names. Are there any ways to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft network monitor can capture packets and sort them based on the process name. I would use that as a starting point.